# Keras discrepancy between test and train

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train an autoencoder in keras. 
At a certain point, the training procedure started to go wrong.

Unfortunately I didn't keep track of the development. But I know that the error has to be here

```
def __compile_models__(self):

    metrics_factory = MetricsFactory()

    loss = [metrics_factory.ReconstructionLoss()]*1
    metrics = {'decoder1_output': metrics_factory.RSquareMetrics()}#,
               #'decoder2_output': metrics_factory.RSquareMetrics(),
               #'decoder3_output': metrics_factory.RSquareMetrics(),
               #'decoder4_output': metrics_factory.RSquareMetrics()}

    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=.99, beta_2=.999, epsilon=1e-8)
    self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics)

def __get_callbacks__(self):
    log = callbacks.CSVLogger(self.model_name+'_training.log')
    sbm = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=self.model_name+'_best.w',
        save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)
    return [log, sbm]

def train(self, x_train, x_test, iters=1000, epochs=100):

    self.__compile_models__()
    callbacks = self.__get_callbacks__()

    self.autoencoder.fit_generator(
        generator=x_train,
        steps_per_epoch=iters,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        validation_data=x_test,
        validation_steps=220)

    self.autoencoder.save_weights(self.model_name+'_last.w')
```

What happens is that I have a huge discrepancy between train and test, even when the datasets are the same.

```
220/220 [==============================] - 725s 3s/step - 
loss: 5174.9836 - metrics: 0.5704 - 
val_loss: 214298.1528 - val_metrics: -16.9736
```

As far as I know there are no differences between training and testing in the network itself (e.g. dropout, regularizations...)

Has anyone of you experienced the same problem?

Comment: You're probably [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) on the data. That is: you train it too much so that the AE only learns the data you use.

Comment: I also thought so, but then I tried to use the same batch generator for both training and testing, and the result is the one you see above.

Comment: Training and testing losses will never be the same due to regularization, which is turned off when evaluating metrics at test time.

Comment: No regularisation used.